# IP address alias? E.g. map 203.0.113.37 to 127.0.0.1?

Tags: networking

I want to use an SSH tunnel to work on a project, `-L 8080:localhost:80`. When opening `http://localhost:8080` on my local machine things work, but the server (MediaWiki) is putting a lot of `http://203.0.113.37/` ([example IP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5737)) in the HTML source served and this address does not go anywhere from my localhost.

Is there a way to map 203.0.113.37 to 127.0.0.1 on my local machine? E.g. something like `/etc/hosts` but then for IP addresses.

(Ideally I want this to work on OS X.)

Comment: use `ssh -D 1080` instead of port forwarding and configure your browser to use a SOCKS proxy via localhost:1080 (all browser traffic will be routed via that ssh SOCKS tunnel).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks. This is a good workaround. I'd still like to know if "IP aliases" are possible though.

Comment: That would have to be done via some LD_PRELOAD wrapper, DNAT at the firewall level (don't know about OS/X), or some other form of proxying (HTTP proxy or SOCKS proxy doing the translation on the fly).

Comment: Actually, if you configure your browser to HTTP-proxy via `localhost:8080`, it would probably work. It would issue some `GET http://203.0.113.37/... HTTP/1.1`... to the remote web server which it should treat properly.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds liks a problem which can more easily be solved within your HTTP config.  See if you can set the hostname on the server to be localhost for the testing period, and/or disable canonicalname redirection.

I think that convincing the webserver NOT to send that canonical IP will prevent the problem you're trying to solve with a networking/hosts fix.